# What is the best method to output the correct HTML from my PHP loop

Tags: php, html, css, zend-framework

I have a problem, I have a HTML problem, I don't know if i'm using the best method, so here is my problem:
Everthing is ok:http://screencast.com/t/uJmffaxE
If i have more space, here are starting the problems: http://screencast.com/t/1z1GRhOLK
**Here is my code:**

```
<div id="wrap-categories" class="clearfix">
<?php if($this->categories !== false): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($this->categories as $category):?>
        <li>
            <strong><?=$category['name']?></strong><br />
        <?php if($this->artistsHelper($category['id']) !== false): ?>
            <?php foreach($this->artistsHelper($category['id']) as $artist): ?>
                <p><?=$artist['name']?></p>
            <?php endforeach; ?>    
        <?php endif; ?>
        </li>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**And here is how the markup looks like, when is generated:**

```
            <div id="wrap-categories" class="clearfix">

                                <ul>
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Dj's</strong><br />
                                                                                <p>Big artists</p>
                                                        <p>asddssdadsasda</p>
                                                        <p>Gigle bossu</p>

                                            </li>   
                                        <li>

                        <strong>Make up</strong><br />
                                                                                <p>Cool</p>

                                            </li>   
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Mamam</strong><br />
                                            </li>   
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Tata</strong><br />

                                            </li>   
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Dawaj</strong><br />
                                            </li>   
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Sexy</strong><br />
                                            </li>   
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Bitch</strong><br />

                                            </li>   
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Armin</strong><br />
                                            </li>   
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Lol</strong><br />
                                            </li>   
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Gogu</strong><br />

                                            </li>   
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Penal</strong><br />
                                            </li>   
                                        <li>
                        <strong>Asasin</strong><br />
                                            </li>   
                                    </ul>
                        </div>
```

**The css**

```
#wrap-categories ul li{
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

Any help please?!

Comment: Is your issue that the markup appears large with all the whitespace?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/1z1GRhOLK here, the categories(strong titles) should go under the first category...

Comment: If you're showing tabular data, use a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php $x = 1?>         
 <?php if($this->categories !== false): ?>
    <?php foreach($this->categories as $category):?>
        <div class="column" <?=($x == 6) ? "style=\"clear:left\"" : false;?>>
            <ul>
                <li class="category"><?=$category['name']?></li> <!-- header data... -->
            <?php if($this->artistsHelper($category['id']) !== false): ?>
                    <?php foreach($this->artistsHelper($category['id']) as $artist): ?>
                            <li><?=$artist['name']?></li> <!-- no class info here because its just text -->
                    <?php endforeach; ?>    
            <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php ($x == 6) ? $x = 1 : $x++;?>
         </div>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues to tackle. First, UL stands for Un-ordered List and is great if all you had was the first column of data there. I can only assume that you will need to fill out more columns of data (across the horizontal axis), so UL is the wrong parent tag. If *were* the correct tag, you would need to append opening and closing LI (for list item) tags.

@Jonathan Sampson's comment is correct. You will see a lot of posts here and elsewhere online saying how evil tables are, and that is true when misused for layout purposes. <strike>Based on what you have shown us, you have tabular data and that *should* be using a Table tag as a parent.</strike>

**Update**

It appears I misunderstood the nature of your data. After going back and forth, *this* is your solution:

```
<style type="text/css">

     .column
     {
          float: left;
          display: inline;
          clear: none;
          margin: 0 5px;
     }

     .column UL LI 
     {
          list-style: none;
     }


     .category
     {
         font-weight: bold;
     }
 </style>

 <div> <!-- this is an outer/wrapper/container -->
 <?php if($this->categories !== false): ?>
    <?php foreach($this->categories as $category):?>
        <div class="column">
            <ul>
                <li class="category"><?=$category['name']?></li> <!-- header data... -->
            <?php if($this->artistsHelper($category['id']) !== false): ?>
                    <?php foreach($this->artistsHelper($category['id']) as $artist): ?>
                            <li><?=$artist['name']?></li> <!-- no class info here because its just text -->
                    <?php endforeach; ?>    
            <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
         </div>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

There are a few differences in what I posted here and what you started with:

- Wrap each column in a floating DIV
- Wrap each "artist" in a pair of LIs
- Wrap the whole thing in a container DIV
- Set the appearance of your header row in the style sheet

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use stylesheet (css) to make that works. try to add fixed width into your list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right your problem is with the source code indentation. Is it correct?
[Here will be your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901502/line-breaks-and-indentation-in-html-output).
I had this problem when I use the Source Code -> Format option from Netbeans IDE:

```
        <div class="for">
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
<p> <!-- this "p" without indentation will be correct rendered -->
paragraph
            </p> <!-- this one will always render wrongly -->
           <?php endfor; ?>
```

But if use the Souce Code -> Format option or indent it by yourself it will be rendered with extra indentation.
Using print or echo it dindn't go wrong.